# How to find lost horse?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm in a HUMONGOUS RPG map, and I fenced in a horse near the edge of a forest. I have two problems:

- I want my horse back
- I want to find the area where that was

I can't find the area, and I want to get there. I know commands to tp the horse to me, but I want to find that whole area, not just the horse. So is there a command to locate the horse? A command that will just give me the coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no command to locate an entity.

There is however a way, but be aware that this will always require the horse to be loaded first of all, so you need to be inside render distance from it or it has to be in the spawn chunks.

You do `/tp @p @e[type=horse,c=1]` to teleport yourself to the nearest horse.

You can also try to do `/tp @e[type=horse] ~ ~ ~`. This should print the coordinates of every loaded horse in chat, because it will teleport them to the coordinates where they already are and return the success message containing the coordinates (be aware this this will be different in version 1.13).

Comment: Can't you get an identifier for a specific horse?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "identifier"?

Comment: According to https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Chunk_format every entity has got a UUID.

Comment: yes, every entity has a UUID. but I'm not sure how it would help you? chances are, you never wrote down that identifier.
If you however have that identifier, you may be able to look up the entities coordinates using an external tool, like NBT explorer.

Comment: Well the idea is that you back up the id when you get the horse. Also, you could improve your approach by filtering out the horses that look different, since the horse looks configuration is in the data structure.

Comment: still, the problem is getting the UUID in the first place. because who writes down the UUIDs of the entities they encounter? that number is basically 0. And OP wanted a way to find their horse in a specific scenario, so that approach wouldn't help at all.

Comment: Maybe there's a log listing all events, including horse spawning that could be cross-referenced against the time when op found the horse?

Comment: There is not. The game doesn't save any arbitrary action you make to the log file. Also, the horse probably didn't spawn there but was placed there by the map maker. So no, this doesn't help.

Comment: If it was placed there by the map maker, you can start a new game and check the horse.

Comment: The problem is that they don't find the area anymore. So they wont find the horse either???

Comment: Isn't the starting area always the same? So the search can be optimized by gradually working your way outside and around the starting chunk.

Comment: I did nametag my horse. Will it list nametags?

Comment: And you're telling me this NOW? You can do `@e[type=horse,name=Whateveryounamedyourhorse]` in the teleport then if there are no spaces or commas in the name to get teleported to the horse directly (if it's loaded).

Answer (score 2):

With the new 1.13 update, that command does not work but you can use:

```
/tp @e[type=minecraft:horse,limit=1,sort=nearest]
```

to teleport you to the nearest horse.

Comment: That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@e[type=horse,name=whateveryounamedyourhorse]` in the teleport, then, if there are no spaces or commas in the name, you get teleported to the horse directly (if it's loaded).

I did this and I found my horse Maximus.

Comment: i go my horse back and i am happy thanks arqade i am really happy